# Tkinter Notebook open new tab along with already open tab like vscode

Tags: tkinter

I have an application in tkinter where I have used notebook to make tabs.

And there are two buttons in the application. *On click button, a new tab open.*

But there is a problem when I click on the second button the previous tab is replaced by the new tab.

**I want to open that new tab along with the existing tab.**

Please help

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno

root = Tk()

root.title('Switch Pages')
root.geometry('500x500')
root.minsize(400, 400)

# Frame
button_frame = Frame(root, height=50, bg='red')
button_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH)

button1 = Button(button_frame, text="Button 1", command=lambda: notebook_tab(0))
button1.grid(row=0, column=5)
button2 = Button(button_frame, text="Button 2", command=lambda: notebook_tab(1))
button2.grid(row=0, column=6)


# Main Frame
main_frame = Frame(root, bg='yellow')
main_frame.pack()

def notebook_tab(no):
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(main_frame)

    tab1 = Frame(notebook)
    tab2 = Frame(notebook)

    notebook.add(tab1, text='Snooker Table 1')
    notebook.add(tab2, text='Snooker Table 2')
    notebook.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    notebook.hide(tab1)
    notebook.hide(tab2)

    def select(no):
        notebook.select(no)

    select(no)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Help us help you - provide a minimal amount of code that reproduces your situation.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't create new tabs in an existing notebook, it creates a new notebook each time. Is that what you're asking about - how to _not_ create a new notebook every time? The solution seems obvious: don't create a new notebook every time.